# get td jstl value by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get value of td and print it to textbox but td has jstl value so it get the first value in arraylist but I want to get the current value in td when user click it.
Can anyone help me how  can I do that?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.contacts table td").live('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("contactName").value=
         document.getElementById("contactId").innerHTML;
  });
});
```

input text and td

```
 <input type="text" id="contactName">

 <td id="contactId">{{contact.email}}</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take the HTML of the clicked element, which is `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.contacts table td").live('click', function() {
     $("#contactName").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

---

Note that the `live()` method is deprecated. You should use `on` instead.

---

Demo, using `on`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.contacts").on('click', "table td", function() {
    $("#contactName").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="contactName">
<div class="contacts">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alice</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Carol</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using your code in opposite way:

```
document.getElementById("contactName").value=
         document.getElementById("contactId").innerHTML;
```

Should be:

```
     document.getElementById("contactId").innerHTML=
         document.getElementById("contactName").value;
```